# If $0 < x < y$, show that $x < (x+y)/2 < y$ is true

Tags: inequality

> If $0 < x < y$, show that $x < (x+y)/2 < y$ is true.

I think this is an easy question, but I just can't see its solution.  I thought I could add $x$ to all the terms, then I'd get $x < 2x < y + x$. From this, I could say that $2x < y +x$, so $x < (y+x)/2$. But I can't think in anything to keep with the solution.

Comment: why should we have $x>0$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $x<y,$
$$ 2x = x+x < x+y < y+y = 2y. $$
Now divide by $2$ throughout.

Comment: oh, I understand now. I was with my mind closed, thinking that I only could add things in all the terms  at once, like when you do with a equation. But now i'm clarified. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $0<x<y$ then $y<x+y<2y$ implies $\frac{y}{2}<\frac{x+y}{2}<y$.

If $x<\frac{x+y}{2}$ then $2x=x+x<x+y$, which is true. Hence $x<\frac{x+y}{2}<y$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since $x<y$, you can consider $y=x+a, a>0$. Now substitute:
$$\color{red}x < \color{green}{(x+y)/2} < \color{blue}y \iff \\
\color{red}x<\color{green}{\frac{x+x+a}{2}=x+\frac a2}<\color{blue}{x+a},$$
which is true.